# Backward compatible change of a web service API?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, backwards-compatibility

Are there any guidelines for adding new functionality (or other changes) to a web service and remain backward compatible?

A concrete example: Adding a new (optional) parameter to a method will still accept old API calls (because the XML request is identical).

Example 2: Adding a new option output parameter will also match 100% the old API in cases when the new parameter is not present.

But the WSDL will differ between old and new version. Are there clients (frameworks) that check the WSDL at runtime?
Any other considerations?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have been going through the same problem. To answer your question – it depends. My research over the net tells me that allowing the new optional parameters in response should be allowed but this has to be a part of pre-condition between client and service provider.

If you add any optional parameter to the request query or input parameters then you must handle it at server side or provide default implementation.

In the response, as I said based on agreement with service provider you may or may not.

See the [guidelines for youtube APIs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/compatibility_guidelines).